# Shared functions across multiple angular components called on click

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an Angular website that has several components. Many of these components include displaying text that links to other components. I route to these other components with an html element like this:

```html
<a (click)='routeToTeamSeason(team_season_id)' [routerLink]>{{team}}</a>
```

and then the function looks like:

```js
routeToTeamSeason(team_season_id: string): void{
        console.log("Routing to: " + team_season_id)
        this.router.navigate(['/teams/season', team_season_id])
}
```

Where router is an instance of the @angular/router class.

Several of my components all can use this same routing logic, and right now I have the same exact function copy and pasted into each component's .ts file. How can I create a shared function that will be recognized by each component's html template?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best method, but here is the solution I found:

create a separate file route-to-team-season.ts:

```js
export function routeToTeamSeason(team_season_id: string): void{
    console.log("Routing to: " + team_season_id)
    this.router.navigate(['/teams/season', team_season_id])
}
```

Then import that function into any component and declare it locally:

```js
myRouteToTeamSeason = routeToTeamSeason
```

Finally, update the template to call `myRouteToTeamSeason(...)`

This seems a little ugly to me, so if someone has a nicer solution, let me know!

Comment: Does angular provide anything similar to namespace in c#, for example abclib.xyz.mymethod() something ?.